# Success run iOS App, but got failed when archive to upload in App Store

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, upload, archive

I am building an app using Flutter. I can run it on the simulator, but when I try to archive it for upload to the App Store via Xcode I get this error:

> .../ios/Pods/Target Support Files/sqflite/sqflite-umbrella.h:13:9
> double-quoted include "SqfliteCursor.h" in framework header, expected
> angle-bracketed instead

[image: one of some error example]

I was try some method, but nothing has changed, like:

1. Change value

> Change value of **CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER** to **NO**
> [image: value]

2. remove ios folder

> 1. Backup **Runner** folder
> 2. delete **Ios** folder (it will automatically create folder ios)
> 3. then, copy **Runner** to **ios** folder
> 4. run **flutter create .** (flutter will build some missing file)
> 5. **cd ios/**, and then run **pod install**
> 6. **cd ..**, then **flutter run**, it will success run on simulator. but i still got same error when try to archive